# I don't understand why I can't retrieve parameters from a form in Java EE

Tags: java, html, web-services, web, jax-rs

I'm currently learning Java EE and I was doing an exercice where you retrieve data from a form that uses method POST.
I reproduce the code from the course I'm taking but it does not work for me. The original code uses such line `public Response add(@Context UriInfo info) {String someParam = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("someParamName"); // and further code}` but it does not work on my side even if it is a simple code. I asked the instructor and so far he couldn't come with an answer for he does not see where the error lies. I looked for code snippets and it really seems to be the good syntax. So I have absolutely no clue why the Params are empty/null.
The browser dev tools says there is data. The code says nothing to retrieve (null). Here is some code.

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>backOffice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**add-work-form.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ajouter une oeuvre.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="rest/work" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Information du nouveau titre:</legend>
            <label for="titre">Titre: </label>
            <input type="text" id="titre" name="titre" /><br />
            <label for="annee">Année: </label>
            <input type="text" name="annee" /><br/>
            <label for="genre">Genre: </label>
            <input type="text" id="genre" name="genre" list="listGenre">
            <datalist id="listGenre">
                <option value="Action">
                <option value="Aventure">
                <option value="Sci-Fi">
                <option value="Fantasy">
                <option value="Nul">
            </datalist><br/>
            <label for=artiste>Artiste principal: </label>
            <input type="text" id="artiste" name="artiste" /><br />
            <label for="resume">Résumé: </label>
            <textarea id="resume" name="resume"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WorkResource**

```java
package com.directmedia.onlinestore.backoffice.resources;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.directmedia.onlinestore.entity.Artist;
import com.directmedia.onlinestore.entity.Catalogue;
import com.directmedia.onlinestore.entity.Work;

@Path("/work")
public class WorkResource {

    public WorkResource() {

    }

    //@Path("/liste")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Set<Work> liste() {
        if (Catalogue.getListOfWorks().isEmpty()) {
            Set<Work> list = new HashSet<Work>();

            Artist harrisonFord = new Artist("Harrison Ford");
            Artist takuyaKimura = new Artist("Takuya Kimura");
            Artist johnnyDepp = new Artist("Johnny Depp");

            Work w1 = new Work("Blade Runner");
            w1.setRelease(1982);
            w1.setMainArtist(harrisonFord);
            w1.setSummary("Un bidule dans le turfu de sa race qui tue.");
            w1.setGenre("Sci-Fi");

            Work w2 = new Work("Antartica");
            w2.setRelease(1983);
            w2.setMainArtist(takuyaKimura);
            w2.setSummary("Taro et Jiro sont en Antartique. Taro tombes à l'eau keski REST ?");
            w2.setGenre("Drame / Aventure");

            Work w3 = new Work("Transcendence");
            w3.setRelease(2014);
            w3.setMainArtist(johnnyDepp);
            w3.setSummary("Une description de moi. ;P ");
            w3.setGenre("Sci-Fi");

            list.add(w1);
            list.add(w2);
            list.add(w3);

            Catalogue.setListOfWorks(list);
        }

        return Catalogue.getListOfWorks();
    }

    @POST
    public Response add(@Context UriInfo info, @QueryParam("genre") String genre) {
        String titre = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("titre");
        Date date = new Date();

        System.out.println("\n========\n========");
        System.out.println(date.toString());
        System.out.println("-> Le titre reçu est:" +titre);
        System.out.println("-> Le genre reçu est:" +genre);

        return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
        }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{numero}")
    public Response modify(@PathParam("numero") int numero) {
        System.out.println("L'oeuvre numéro "+numero+" a été modifiée.");
        return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{numero}")
    public Response delete(@PathParam("numero") int numero) {
        System.out.println("Suppression du titre dont le numéro est "+numero);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

**Some Output**

```
========
========
Fri May 24 20:03:50 GMT+01:00 2019
-> Le titre reçu est:null
-> Le genre reçu est:null
```

From the output you can see that no matter the method, the result is `null`.
You can see on the screenshot that there is some form data.
[image: There is data from the form as the dev tool states]

Should anyone need some extra info please ask.
Should you have any idea to propose, please.

Kind Regards.

Environnement:
Windows 10

Eclipse 4.11

JDK 11

Tomcat 9.0.13

jersey.container.servlet 2.25.1

jersey.media.json.jackson 2.25.1

jstl 1.2

Comment: I tried editing this several times for the greetings got cut. Editing did not help.
So hi all in here and thank you for your time, help and propositions.

Comment: Have you tried with @FormParam? Since your method is POST, parameters are not expected to travel by the queryParam

Comment: No but I was reading a book about it and I was just about to try. The book states if I translate:
@FormParam "this annotation allows it to extract parameters from the body of the request when it comes from a form send with the post method". So QueryParam would be only for GET?
I'll change my form to GET before and then I'll try FormParam.
Thanks.

Comment: Both methods work when I change the post method to GET.
FormParam works with form and POST method.
I knew it would be something stupid for even on a simple code it wasn't working. Many Thanks Jayr. You should have posted as an answer.

Comment: Glad that it worked and yes QueryParam is for GET, which will make the URI appear something like /backOffice/rest/work?genre=Sci-Fi - probably not desirable in some cases (imagine if its for a password field)